# Superscript and Subscript in javafx

Tags: javafx

Can someone suggest a workaround to add Superscript and Subscript controls in the existing javafx HTML editor.
I am trying to develop a Formula field editor having Bold, Italics, Superscript, Subscript and font selector as controls.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible (AFAIK) without some pretty serious hacking, involving accessing parts of the API that are intended not to be accessed. The following more or less works; I based it on the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/web/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/scene/web/skin/HTMLEditorSkin.java) for the `HTMLEditorSkin`. You may need to persuade your IDE to let you access the relevant packages. This is not particularly recommended, and it almost certainly will not work in Java 9.

```
import com.sun.javafx.webkit.Accessor;
import com.sun.webkit.WebPage;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.HTMLEditor;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HTMLEditorHack extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        HTMLEditor editor = new HTMLEditor();
        Scene scene = new Scene(editor);
        editor.applyCss();
        editor.layout();

        WebView webView = (WebView) editor.lookup(".web-view");
        ToolBar toolbar = (ToolBar) editor.lookup(".bottom-toolbar");
        ToggleGroup toggleGroup = new ToggleGroup();

        createToggleButton("superscript", "Super", toggleGroup, webView, toolbar);
        createToggleButton("subscript", "Sub", toggleGroup, webView, toolbar);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void createToggleButton(String command, String label, ToggleGroup toggleGroup, WebView webView, ToolBar toolbar) {
        ToggleButton button = new ToggleButton(label);
        button.setFocusTraversable(false);
        button.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isSelected) -> {
            WebPage page = Accessor.getPageFor(webView.getEngine());
            if (page.queryCommandState(command) != isSelected) {
                page.executeCommand(command, null);
            }
        });
        button.setToggleGroup(toggleGroup);
        toolbar.getItems().add(button);

        EventHandler<Event> updateState = e -> {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                WebPage page = Accessor.getPageFor(webView.getEngine());
                button.setDisable(! page.queryCommandEnabled(command));
                button.setSelected(page.queryCommandState(command));
            });
        };
        webView.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.ANY, updateState);
        webView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, updateState);
        webView.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, updateState);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

If you need a robust approach for creating an equation editor, I would probably consider building your own, instead of using/hacking `HTMLEditor`. There is a third party library, [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) that can be used to create an editable text area with varying styles. Start there and add your own controls for styling.